# Multiple dispatchers in the action creators causing issues in unit test

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, react-redux, redux-thunk

Following is my action creator with multiple dispatches

```
export function getAnalysisById(Id){
  let url = APIEndpoints["getAnalysisById"];
  var dataObject = {
    id: Id
  }
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch ({
                       type:LOADING_ANALYSIS,
                       payload : { isLoading : true}
           });
    const request = axios.post(url, dataObject);
    dispatch ({
                       type:GET_ANALYSIS_BY_ID,
                       payload: request
           });
  };
}
```

Now following is the testing code written for the above action

```
var  chai  = require('chai');

var expect = chai.expect;
const actions = require('../../src/actions/index');

import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import nock from 'nock'
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise'
const middlewares = [ thunk,ReduxPromise ]


import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'


const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)


describe("All actions WITH Asynchronous call",function description(){
  it('should return an action to get All Analysis by id', () => {
  const store = mockStore({})

 // Return the promise
  return store.dispatch(actions.getAnalysisById('costnomics_Actual vs Budjected'))
    .then(() => {
      // const actionss = store.getActions()
       console.log('store',store)

    })
}) 


});
```

Running the above test case produces the following error,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

When I pass plain objects as return value for the action creators instead of dispatcher, everything is working fine. But when mulitple dispatchers are returned from the action creator, it gives me the above error?. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your thunk function isn't actually returning a promise.  You need to have something like `return request` at the end so that the promise is returned from the thunk, and from there returned from `store.dispatch()`.